# Often dragging the top of a window ends up expanding it

Tags: drag-and-drop

very often when I drag the top of windows such as a browser window to move it to another location, Ubuntu expands the window instead. This happens regardless I use an external mouse or a trackpad. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release and desktop compositor or environment?